# Pushing a new viewcontroller via a next button?

Tags: iphone, uitableview, uiview, uiviewcontroller

Sorry I can't show code for this question - it should be fairly simple to explain..

I have an array of data (object1, object2, object3, etc)… I have one tableview that lists these objects (object1.title, object2.title, etc) and upon clicking it push's a viewcontroller that shows the detail of each object. Now, rather than have to press Back on each detail view, I'd like to put a next button on the detail page..

I could easily push a new controller, however it would end with a chain of:

List View -> Detailview1 -> Detailview2, etc..

which would be a pain to traverse back up the stack.. Can the parent view controller be removed / changed easily or is this not the best way to do it?

Cheers.

Comment: I believe you want to traverse forward when clicking next instead going back.  ????

Comment: I do want to traverse forward. Ie - on each detail page have a next button. This would then "push" another view onto the stack of the next detail page, however would alter the parent so it wouldnt be the previous detail page.. ie List View -> detailview1... press next so it shows detailview2.. but the back button would go back to Listview, NOT via detailview1. Does that make sense?

Comment: By default navigation controller's back button would go back. Next button to be placed in the place of back button and next should go to forward. Right?

Answer (score 0):

You can always pop back to a specific index in the stack.  So you could have a back button that pops back to the parent.  If there is no real reason that the user would need to go back through the detail view controllers you could swap controllers by replacing the stack with a new stack using `setViewControllers:animated:`  Look through the UINavigationController documentation and see whats possible.

Comment: Good point, could you also remove from the second controller to the last-1 of the stack and then pop?

Answer (score 0):

This code will "pop" the view contoller off the view, so it removes it, instead of overlaying another view on top of it.  Add this to your button action

```
 [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```